# React Router and Redux Data Persistence Issue on Page Refresh

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have an App component where I've implemented React Router for navigating between different pages, including a 'Home' page and a 'Course' page. In the 'Home' page, I dispatch an action to fetch data from an API. However, in the 'Course' page, I'm using the useSelector method to retrieve data from the Redux store. The problem I'm encountering is that when I refresh the 'Course' page, the data in the Redux store becomes empty, and I have to go back to the 'Home' page to fetch the data again.

Home page :

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { getCoursesFun } from '../action/course'
import Lists from '../components/Lists'
import CoursesList from './CoursesList'
import Hero from '../components/Hero/Hero'
const Home = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()


    useEffect(() => {


        dispatch(getCoursesFun())

    }
        , [])
    return (
        <div>
            <Hero />

            <Lists />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home
```

Course Page :

```
import { getCoursesFun } from '../action/course';
import Courses from '../components/Courses/Courses';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const CoursesList = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const data = useSelector((state) => state.courseReducer.courses);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!data) {
      console.log("data is null"  , data)
      // Dispatch the action to fetch data
      dispatch(getCoursesFun())
      console.log(data)
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
        });
    }
  }, [data, dispatch]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Courses Coursesdata={data} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default CoursesList;
```

looking for a solution to this issue. Should I dispatch the action to fetch data at the App component level, or are there other solutions that might work better?"

Comment: Redux is an in-memory state management solution, when you reload the page, anything in memory is dumped. You'll need to persist/initialize the Redux store to/from longer-term storage. If you need help with this then please [edit] the post to include the relevant Redux code that needs to be persisted. See [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dispatch the global states in top level component like `</App>`.

You don't need `useEffect` the component will re-render every time the state value is changed.

```
import { getCoursesFun } from '../action/course';
import Courses from '../components/Courses/Courses';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const CoursesList = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const data = useSelector((state) => state.courseReducer.courses);

  if(!data){ // your loading component
       return (<div>Loading....</div>)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Courses Coursesdata={data} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default CoursesList;
```